# Cast `size_t[]` to `char *` without C-style casting or `reinterpret_cast`

Tags: c++, casting

In order to count the set bits in a `size_t[n]`, I've created a `LUT[256]` with pre-calculated number of set bits per a single byte.

To use `std::accumulate` and iterate over each byte in a `const size_t[n]`, casting to `const char *` is required.

In `C`, `(const char *)arrSizet` would work.
In `C++` I could use one the following options:

1. `reinterpret_cast<const char *>(arrSizet)`
2. `char arrChar[BYTES_IN_SIZET_ARR]; memcpy(arrChar, arrSizet, BYTES_IN_SIZET_ARR);`

`C` style cast or using `reinterpret_cast` (1) should generally be avoided if possible.
While (2) copies the array unnecessarily.

So is there any better approach to get this done? Perhaps a way to sent bytes array to `std::accumulate` without any casting?

Comment: Down voted instantly after posting, not even 2 seconds passed. Seriously? At least give it 10 seconds to go through the post for gods sake. Or have the courtesy to write a comment explaining how to improve it.

Comment: "How do I do X without doing X?"

Comment: Even after rereading the post a couple of times, I still have no idea what you're trying to do. Taking your title at face value is simply what Caleth said: how do I do X without doing X.

Comment: Why can't you directly work with the `size_t[]`? Something's tingling in my mind, telling me that casting _to_ char* isn't a good idea because of alignment.

Answer (score -1):

Casting is sometimes necessary in c++ it shouldn't be looked down upon. Memcpy is a much more dangerous operation than a cast. There are ways of getting around casting in your situation by making your own accumulate and using bitwise operations for a sum but c++ at its core is made for stuff like casting.